# Move smaller operand into larger operand

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm having a little trouble with imagining how data moves into the RAX register.

Here is the assembly language:

```
.data
dwordVal DWORD 94326732h
.code
mov rax, 0FFFFFFFF00000000h
mov rax, dwordVal
```

I read that you cannot move a smaller operand into a larger operand with MOV. It seems to me that dwordVal would only fill the lower half of the 64 bit rax register, so this would not be permitted. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you are using an assembler that treats `dwordVal` as a memory reference, that `mov` will mindlessly load 64 bits even though you only defined data for 32. If your assembler uses that as an address, then of course you are just loading a 64 bit address which is fine.

Comment: so the first mov operation initializes the rax register, and the second mov fills in the lower half if I am understanding correctly

Comment: You should quite often try these things in debugger. If you would for example define `dwordVal DWORD 94326732h, 0deadf00dh` and do `mov rax, dwordVal`, depending on your assembler the `rax` would contain either address of first byte of `94326732h` value, or qword value from memory `0deadf00d94326732h` (both dwords loaded), both clearly disagreeing with your initial idea. Watching things in debugger while single-stepping instructions is usually best second source of knowledge (right next after reading the pure theory in the instruction reference guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `mov` instruction will always fill the destination operand with a complete value, of exactly the same size as the destination operand.

So, your understanding is incorrect. You cannot fill part of `rax` with a `mov`.

As Jester has already said in a comment, precisely what will happen as a result of that `mov rax, dwordVal` depends on the conventions followed by your assembler, and some assemblers would actually reject such a thing as illegal.

One thing I can tell you is that there will be absolutely nothing left in `rax` from that `0FFFFFFFF00000000h` that was previously loaded into it.

Comment: Well, you can fill part of `rax` by `mov` like `mov ax,1` or `mov al,1` or `mov ah,1` and similar. But only the low 16 bits of `rax` are available for such modification (and it is often penalized performance-wise, to make code which is generally faster, one should rather load both values into 64b registers first, and then merge with `or` or `add` instruction). `mov eax,1` will clear also upper 32 bits, so full `rax` is initialized.